# Python getting days of the month out of an input from a user in the program

Tags: python, date, datetime, if-statement

This is what I'm trying to do :

The user will input a year, a month number (1-12), and a day number in that order. The program will determine if the date is in the future, or in the past. (If the date entered is today’s date, assume the date is in the past). A future date is a date that has not happened yet. If today is July 31st,August 1 of the same year is not in the past, just because the day(1)comes before today’s day (31). For the input, if the user enters an invalid month, display an appropriate error message(like “Invalid Month”) and end the program. If the user enters an invalid day, display an appropriate error message (like“Invalid Day”) and end the program. Assume 28 days in February. In other words, if the month is February and the day entered is 29, display the error message and end the program. Remember:
Thirty days has September,April, June, and November All the rest have 31 Except February, which has 28....

Define a function called
inTheFuture()
that accepts a given year number, a month number, and a day number as 3 separate arguments. The function should return a Boolean value (True or False) to indicate whether the date (year, month, and day) parameters  are in the future or not. A True return occurs if the date is in the future; false if the date is in the past.It should not draw any images or text to the screen. It also should not ask the user for input.It just determines if a given date is in the future or not. Find an image to represent the future, and an image to represent the past. Examples could include something like “The Jetson’s” for the future, and an old wagon for the past. If the date is in the future, display your future image in the middle of a canvas. If the date is in the past, display your past image in the middle of the canvas. At the top of the canvas, display “In the future” or “In the past”, whichever matches the image. To find the current date, you may add this import and function to your code:
import datetime
def getTodaysDate():
return datetime.datetime.today();
If you call this function somewhere in your code:
today = getTodaysDate();
Then you can use the year, month, and day member variables to obtain the current year, month, andday. For example:
print(today.month);
would output the current month

this is my coding so far,  I'm having issues figuring out how to get my invalid day error message to show up for different month. For example I'm suppose to have only 28 days, and 30 in April, June, September, November, and 31 for the rest.  I've tried for a couple of hours doing testing different things, but cant get it to work:

```
import sys
import tkinter
import datetime
import calendar

def getTodaysDate():
    return datetime.datetime.today();
today = getTodaysDate();
print(today)

#def inTheFuture():



year= input ("Enter Year: ");
month= int(input ("Enter Month: "));
day= int(input ("Enter Day: "));


if (month > 12):
    print("invalid Month")
    raise SystemExit
if (month == 1,3,5,7,8,10,12):
    (day > 31)
    print("Invalid Day")
    raise SystemExit
else:
    (month == 2)
    (day > 28)
    print("Invalid Day")
    raise SystemExit
else:
    (month == 4,6,9,11)
    (day > 30)
    print("Invalid Day")
    raise SystemExit
```

Comment: The syntax you're looking for is `if (month == 1 and day > 31):` etc.

Comment: would be better if you can frame your question in brief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like your homework allows using the `datetime` module, just ask it to validate:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date(date.today().year,2,29)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: day is out of range for month
>>> date(date.today().year,13,31)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Otherwise, here's a hint with your syntax:

```
if (month == 1,3,5,7,8,10,12):
    (day > 31)
```

doesn't work and should be written:

```
if month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] and day > 31:
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you this got me started in the right direction.  :)